# Is "cleared away" the right term to use in this sentence?

Tags: word-usage, phrases, idioms, sentence

I am posting a photograph of the sky after the super-cyclone Amphani cleared away in Kolkata. 
Is **cleared away** the right phrase to use? (For a natural calamity)

This is the text that I wrote in the body:

*Several hours after the super-cyclone Amphan cleared away and the Sky got rejuvenated with Pure Vibrancy!*

Any constructive criticism will be greatly appreciated!

Many thanks

Comment: Did the cyclone move on or dissipate? (& 'the Sky got rejuvenated with Pure Vibrancy' sounds off to my ears. I'd prefer 'leaving a sky rejuvenated with _pure vibrancy_.)

Comment: The phrasal verb [*clear away*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clear%20away): "to remove (something) from an area or surface —sometimes used figuratively." The use here is understandable. Whether or not there is something preferable is a matter of opinion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks so much! I will make the changes now :)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The cyclone moved on to the northern part of the state several hours before the picture was taken. The sky here was totally clear by then. As you may know, a cyclone has a head, an eye and a tail and it covers a very large area. Normal cyclones happen here all the time, but this was the first-ever super-cyclone here since 18th century. So it continued to weaken and moved on to the northern lands, and finally dissipated at approximately 300-400 km from here (North), The cyclone travelled a total distance of 500 km approx (I think till Malda, Dinajpur, West Bengal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word *cleared* is used in association with storm:

- However, it looks like the storm has cleared
- Make sure that the storm has cleared out of your way before returning home.
- By morning, our last at the inn, the storm had cleared.

But not *cleared away*.

I looked for the best ways to say that a calamity is over (not liking the usage *over* to be honest) and it looks like *cleared* stand-alone is the best option.

So I'd go with - **Several hours after the super-cyclone Amphan cleared.**

Also, I believe it is **Amphan** and not Amphani, probably a typo.

PS: I had a doubt so I googled "Amphani" prior to posting this answer and google gave me results to "Amphan". Although a forceful search does return a few results with the term Amphani as well.

Hope this helps.

NS

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful :) Yes, I am sorry. It was a typing mistake (the spelling)

Comment: Great. Glad to know it helped.